# How to store this html data back to another database

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

Here I iterate data from my database in mongodb i just want that when my add to cart button is clicked it gets stored into another database named cart and gets displayed on another page

```
{% for data in product_data %}
                    <div class="shop-item" >
                        <span class="shop-item-title" id="title-item">{{ data.title }}</span>
                        <input type="image" class="shop-item-image" id="image-item" src={{ data["img_file"] }} onclick="takethatpage();">
                        <div class="shop-item-details">
                            <span class="shop-item-price" id="price-item">{{ data["price"]}}</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not spoon feed but let me tell you the approach for it.

1. Firstly you would need an API implemented at the server end to accept products to be added to the cart for the respective user.
2. Secondly, for your template there needs to be an AJAX request fired each time the person click on the add to cart button.